# How to set RGBA Color of a Pixel of an UIImage

Tags: objective-c, colors, uiimage, pixel, rgba

I am looking for a possibility to set (change) the RGBA color of a Pixel of an UIImage for my Iphone Application. (I actually want to implement some floodfill stuff)

So I need something like this:

```
-(void) setPixelColorOfImage: (UIImage*) img atXCord: (int) x atYCord: (int) y
withRedColor: (CGFloat) red blueColor: (CGFloat) blue greenColor: (CGFloat) green
alpha: (CGFloat) alpha  {

// need some code her

}
```

Because this method will be called quite often, it shouldn't be too slow.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIImage is not (externally) mutable, so you must copy, then edit, then convert to UIImage.

**Copy**

- create a CGBitmapContext
- draw the source image onto it

**Edit**

- get a hold of the context's pixel buffer
- mutate that pixel buffer

**Convert to UIImage**

- copy a CGImage representation of the context
- create a new UIImage from the CGImage

fwiw, the form can also be used on osx (using NSImage).